# Tweeting using Powershell

Tags: api, http, powershell, twitter

I'm trying to use PowerShell to tweet but it I can't get it to work fully.
  I'm able to make 1 or 2 tweets and yes I wait a few minutes in between each and I dont repeat the previous message.

Then of a sudden it stops working, my `GetRequestStream` function hangs, I'm not sure whats happening, can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net")  

$status = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("tweet tweet");  
$oauth_consumer_key = "<key";  
$oauth_consumer_secret = "<secret>";  
$oauth_token = "<token>";  
$oauth_token_secret = "<secret>";  
$oauth_nonce = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks.ToString()));  
$ts = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow - [System.DateTime]::ParseExact("01/01/1970", "dd/MM/yyyy", $null).ToUniversalTime();  


$oauth_timestamp = [System.Convert]::ToInt64($ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();  

$signature = "POST&";  
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json") + "&";    
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_consumer_key=" + $oauth_consumer_key + "&");  
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_nonce=" + $oauth_nonce + "&");   
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&");  
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_timestamp=" + $oauth_timestamp + "&");  
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_token=" + $oauth_token + "&");  
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_version=1.0&");  
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("status=" + $status);  

$signature_key = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_consumer_secret) + "&" + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_token_secret);  

$hmacsha1 = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1;  
$hmacsha1.Key = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($signature_key);  
$oauth_signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hmacsha1.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($signature)));  

$oauth_authorization = 'OAuth ';  
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_consumer_key="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_consumer_key) + '",';  
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_nonce="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_nonce) + '",';  
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_signature="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_signature) + '",';  
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",'  
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_timestamp="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_timestamp) + '",'  
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_token="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_token) + '",';  
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_version="1.0"';  

$post_body = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("status=" + $status);   
[System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");  
$request.Method = "POST";  
$request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $oauth_authorization);  
$request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
$body = $request.GetRequestStream();  
$body.write($post_body, 0, $post_body.length);  
$body.flush();  
$body.close();  
$response = $request.GetResponse();  
 $response.Close()
```

This is the full error sequence i get when it finally times out:

```
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
At line:46 char:5
+     $body = $request.GetRequestStream();
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Exception calling "Write" with "3" argument(s): "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly."
At line:47 char:5
+     $body.write($post_body, 0, $post_body.Length);
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or 
SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse."
At line:50 char:5
+     $response = $request.GetResponse();
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProtocolViolationException
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you closing your response-stream? They are keep-alive connections as default, so if you open to many of them your may be blocked because of two many concurrent sessions. Try using:

```
$response.Close()
```

Comment: Didnt't help, I waited it out and posted the error sequence above. It seemded related the header which is weird considering it worked the two first times, anway I added $request.ContentLength = $post_body.Length and now i get a 403 forbidden instead.